Cloudflare not reaching EC2 with https, can access through IPv4 just fine
I have a React app using create-react-app running on an EC2 and I configured my Cloudflare domain to point to it, everything was working fine - I can access the app both through the IPv4 and through the domain. But then I changed my React app to use https instead of http, and I can no longer access it through the domain - but accessing it through the IPv4 works just fine as before.
What might be the problem here?

When successfully accessing the site via the v4 IP address, are you using https or http?

What SSL mode do you have configured in Cloudflare? Flexible, Full, Strict, Automatic?

@jarmod so I was running http at first - accessing the site using the domain and IPv4 both worked fine. Then, I made the site https - and after that I could only access through the IPv4 not domain.

@MarkB I have flexible on

There has to be something missing here. Perhaps you need to describe exactly what you did when you "changed my React app to use https instead of http". Also, when you say you can "no longer access it through the domain" what is the actual, specific, error message you get?
